# How can I reference a cell in a custom function while setting up data validation in Google spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-custom-function

I made the following Google script to check whether a string is less than some length:

```
function isLengthLessThan(length, text) {
  return (text.length < length)
};
```

How can I set up data validation using this custom formula to check the length of cells? What can I put where the question mark is so that it will represent the value of the cell?

[image: custom formula data validation screen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

```
=len(A1)>9
```

applied to a range starting with A1.